# Redux-Observable - Cancel next request if it has same parameters with current one, but let it run when they are different

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, reactive-programming, redux-observable

I'm new to reactive programming. Just trying to understand observables and rxjs operators. I have a `react-redux` application that has a custom middleware to handle cached data and `isFetching` flags. While it just handles the things I need, it can be complicated for things like cancellation or debouncing. So, I wanted to migrate this application to `redux-observable`.

I want to not fetch the same movie if it is currently fetching. I just pass a `selectIsFetchingMovieById(action.movieId)` selector to the custom middleware. If it returns `true`, it doesn't pass anything to reducers. But when the selector returns `false`, it fetches the movie, runs through either `.then` or `.catch` like any regular promise based fetch data process.

But when I use `redux-observable`, the `isFetching` state for the given movieId is already `true`. Because the reducer already got the `({type: FETCH_MOVIE_REQUEST, movieId: "10" })` action. The selector always returns `true`.

If I use `switchMap`, it will cancel the previous request even if it has a different movieId. `exhaustMap` will not run the next request even if it has a different movieId etc.

Now I have this epic. It works for `cachedData` situation. If the store already has the movie, it won't continue. But `isFetching` based on movieId is still a problem.

```
const fetchMovieEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_MOVIE_REQUEST),
    filter(action => {
      const cachedData = selectors.selectMovie(state$.value, action.movieId);
      return !verifyCachedData(cachedData, action.requiredFields);
    }),
    map(action => action.movieId),
    switchMap(movieId =>
      ajax.getJSON(`${BASE_API_URL}/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${api_key}`).pipe(
        map(response => normalize(response, schemas.movieSchema)),
        map(normalizedData => fetchMovieSuccess(movieId, normalizedData)),
        catchError(() => of(fetchMovieError())),
        takeUntil(
          action$.pipe(
            ofType("FETCH_MOVIE_CANCELLED"),
            filter(action => action.movieId === movieId)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

How can I use rxjs operators or any other technique to fullfil this? I don't want to add an extra actionType like `FETCH_MOVIE_TOGGLE_LOADING`. I already have `REQUEST`, `SUCCESS`, `ERROR` and `CANCELLED`. And there are a lot of other reducers and epics. So, keeping it simple with operators might be a good option :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a little late and I have actually dropped using redux-observable. I was not able to write the code that I want with it. It makes me feel like it's not easily readable.

Sticking with redux-thunk and using redux-saga for special cases might be much more easy. At least for me it is.

Here is the latest version of epics those I've used with the grouping solution:
https://gist.github.com/onderonur/e55f841188263fca5ddd111d218fd505

Answer (score 0):

By definition `exhaustMap` suppose to work. You can probably debug it by restructure  the stream and simplify the inner stream

```
exhaustMap(movieId =>ajax.getJSON(`${BASE_API_URL}/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${api_key}`).pipe(catchError(() => of(fetchMovieError()))
),
```

and see if the subsequent action will fire after request complete

Comment: I'll try it again, but I'm not sure if it will cancel the second request when it has the same movieId as the currently running one, but let it run if it is different.

But like I said, I'm really new to reactive programming. So I might understand its operators wrong :)

I will try and reply again. Thanks !

Comment: I will suggest u remove filter to simplify the test first, how exhaustmap behave is it will skip all all source observable emission until inner observable completes.